# Can I run multiple static websites in an Azure Storage Account using subfolders? I know by default you can only use $web

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-account

For example:

[image: root folder]

rl_bi.htm is my entry point for my "first" static app which I can reach just fine.
Inside the folder SecondStaticApp, I have the following:

[image: Sub folder]

I want to access a second static web page via SecondStaticApp/rl_bi.htm (this is a completely different webpage)

Is it possible to do this? if so, how can I achieve this? (how can I access the second entry point)
I want to do this because my company prefers to keep storage accounts as minimum as possible and I am aware I can only access one static website per storage account using the $web container.

Thank you

Comment: Did you try it? It's just static files so you can put any number of business-wise different "sites" or subfolders into $web as long as you don't care about them sharing the domain part in url. You need separate account only when you want to have a different domain for each site.

Answer (score 1):

As of now , **it can only support one static website for one storage account.**

There is also an [**issue**](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/34608) about that.

You should create a separate Azure Storage Account for each static website. For more information please refer to the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website).